# Hiding H1 from user but making it visible to search engines?

Tags: seo, html, css

I have `h1` tag in a page. I do not want to display it to user but want to make sure that its content will be used for SEO. What is recommended way of achieving it these days. I can think of:

1. in css: `position absolute; left: -99999em;`
2. `display: none;`
3. `visibility: hidden;` (even though it still exists in flow of document)
4. remove `h1` with javascript when page loads

As far as I know 1,2,3 will be easily detected by Google and penalised accordingly, is that right? Would 4 be the only option not resulting in being penalised? What other options are available and safe to use?

BTW I'm not trying to trick user or search engines in any way, it just happens that `h1` is in a way and need to get rid of it.

Comment: If you don't need it why is it there in the first place?

Comment: whether its visible or not it not up to me, I just have to hide it

Comment: Hide it and risk SEO penalties. There is no legitimate reason for this to be hidden Remove it server-side if you can.

Comment: Even option 4 will not help you since the page is downloaded before JS can run. John is right. Do not hide content. If you do not want an h1 tag for the users then remove it. Google will slap you silly and it will be a very long long long road back.

Comment: hmm option 4 would load page as usual, so as far as spiders are concerned these would see H1 in html. Only when DOM is loaded JS would hide H1 somehow. As bad as it sounds this should trick spiders into thinking H1 is visible, am I missing something?

Comment: I echo the above comments. If you don't want an H1 for users, then you shouldn't want it for search engines. Every page can be marked up with a title of some sort - without knowing the context of your scenario, it's hard to explain why, if or how you should markup your web pages but it should come down to, you either use an H1 or you don't; Not one or the other.

Comment: @spirytus Google is getting better at processing JavaScript, so you should assume that Google will detect even #4.

Comment: H1 tags are pretty much just another element now. Bots dont care if its <h1>, <h4>, <span>, <banannas>, or anything else. Use schema.org to define things like this if you want machines to see a page title that humans do not. And YES, its perfectly ok to have hidden schema....look at the case of JSON-LD....its all hidden markup (a script). Just make sure any hidden markup also matches possible visible data. Hiding is one thing, cloaking is another ballgame. So in your case, dont put in an H1 at all. Instead, define its contents for machines with schema title or something.

Comment: google can parse JS? Can anyone point me to a source?

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to go with something like option 4), but instead of using javascript to actually remove `<h1>` from the `DOM` after onload, I would apply a new color style declaration to `<h1>` (in this case, one with 0% opacity).

Something like:

```
<script>
function changeH1Color() {
    var heading1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
    heading1.style.color = 'rgba(63,63,63,0)';
    }

window.onload = changeH1Color();
</script>
```

This function will enable you to change the color of `<h1>` to any color you wish after `onload`, including (if you really wish) a color with 100% alpha-channel transparency.

## =====

After giving consideration to the fact that the intention is for `<h1>` to always remain invisible to sighted human users - while, simultaneously, always existing in the `DOM` - I've realised the post-`onload` script above is probably overkill.

Adding:

```
h1 {
color: rgba(63,63,63,0);
}
```

to the stylesheet ought to suffice.

Comment: This will result in a penalty as well, Google can excecute basic javascript, a simple comparison between 1st DOM and doc-ready DOM and you lose.

Comment: Do you have a source, @Martijn? I am not aware of any official Google position which states that changing the color of a `DOM` element for javascript-capable user-agents incurs a penalty.

Comment: Even if Google doesn't catch this with an algorithm, a manual penalty could be applied for this.   The problem is when you are ranking for the keywords in the H1 tag.  The user clicks to the page and can't actually find that text.   They report you to Google for cloaking and Google issues a manual penalty.

Comment: The usual disclaimer applies that it's entirely Google's affair to decide for itself what it will and what it won't penalise.

Answer (score 1):

*Should be a comment, but can't highlight this enough:*

## Never purposely serve different content to bots.

Comment: On the whole I'd agree with you, @Martijn. But it's also important to consider that there are plenty of situations - e.g. where accessibility needs to be taken into account - where you might want to serve different content to javascript-capable and javascript incapable user agents, aren't there?

Comment: Google provides mechanisms such as [crawlable AJAX](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/) that allow you to show Googlebot the same content that users with JavaScript see.   There is no reason to show Googebot content that normal users can't see.

Comment: @Rounin: Yeah you are correct. But then you use javascript for the benefit of the user, without blackhatting it. If the H1 is not relevant to the user, simply don't show it in the first place (which, is bad because every page needs 1 H1).